# Dynamically modify the form layout in flask-admin based on a field input

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I want to hide/show specific fields in the Flask-Admin form based on the user input on a particular field in the form. How can I do this?

For example, I would like to hide the 'Name' field when 'Selector' is True and hide the 'Nickname' field when 'Selector' is False, for the following model in SQLAlchemy.

```
class Foobar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foobar'

    Selector = Column(Boolean)
    Name = Column(String(100))
    Nickname = Column(String(100))
```

Comment: You want to hide some fields of this form when it is displayed as html on your admin page? You need javascript for that.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want. I was hoping to find a hack within flask-admin. I did consider the drop-down menu approach shown on the [quickstart](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/) page, but am looking for something simpler.

Comment: I'm really not aware of any way you can do it easily with Python (unless websockets)? Some conditional JavaScript, like Pawelmhm said, would make quick work of it.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I'll do it with javascript then. (Websockets won't help.)